# Linking multiple docker containers to one container with alias localhost using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to link a memcache server and a mongo server to my webserver, but the code I have uses localhost as host name for them all. So I want to link them as localhost.

I am doing this-

```
webserver:
  build: ./webserver
ports:
  - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
volumes:
  - /var/www/html:/var/www/html
links:
  - memcachedserver:localhost
  - mongoserver:localhost
```

but after getting into the webserver

```
docker exec -it acb51XXXX081 bash
```

and

```
cat /etc/hosts
```

I'm getting this-

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      adocker_memcachedserver_1 4a11d0cb3126
172.17.0.2      localhost 4a11d0cb3126 adocker_memcachedserver_1
172.17.0.2      memcachedserver_1 4a11d0cb3126 adocker_memcachedserver_1
172.17.0.3      adocker_mongoserver_1 a505d8de4736
172.17.0.3      mongoserver_1 a505d8de4736 adocker_mongoserver_1
```

Only the memcache server is getting the alias localhost, not the mongo server.

After I manually added localhost to mongo's entry, it started working great.

```
172.17.0.3      localhost adocker_mongoserver_1 a505d8de4736
```

But I want to do this automatically in docker-compose.yml file

Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use the same alias to refer to 2 different containers

Comment: Then can you recommend any way to achieve what I have here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give the same name to two different hosts. You really should change your code – hardcoding `localhost` as the host name for different services is a bad idea. (It would be better to have different host names for each service. If they actually run on the same host, you could alias those host names to point to it.)

If you *really* can't change your code, you could set up tunnels from the actual `localhost` to the containers that host the services.

Comment: Hi Dag! I know setting up same alias for different containers is a bad idea, as it isn't just the hostname they work as. I'm gonna try the `net:` dnephin mentioned.
Can you elaborate on the tunnels method you talked about?

Comment: To set up tunnels, you could for instance use the tunnel feature of `ssh`.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have already stated, you can't use the same alias twice.  What you might do instead is to use `net:webserver` in the other services (in v2 this would be `network_mode:webserver`).

That way all the containers will share the same network stack, and localhost will work.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely try that soon. I have to build a Kafka cluster via docker soon, and it'd be really helpful if I was able to get them all under the same network.

Comment: The syntax for version 2 is `network_mode: service:webserver`